# Android drag around many views on a superview

Tags: java, android

I am starting to think that short of OpenGL I can't drag around a simple view.  Seriously, I have read through 10-15 tutorials for dragging views, and EVERY tutorial shows you how to drag a drawable WITHIN a view, or drag an image INSIDE of an imageview (by matrix transformations).  But NONE of the tutorials tell you how you can drag around a simple view in a superview.  Its really that simple.  I have a superview, I add lets say 10 subviews.  Whatever subview my finger is touching drags around.  I made an app for iOS http://www.facebook.com/MakeASnowman (hits the app store any day) and am trying to build it for Android.  But there is no easy way to do things that are so simple in iOS (two finger rotate, drag around views, etc).  This is what I want:  I have a custom view that draws an image to its canvas.  I then instantiate one or more of those custom views onto a "superview".  I can drag/manipulate those views (meaning im not translating the drawables within those views, but the actual views themselves).

Here is my code that has the right manipulations, except it performs them of the drawable within the view:

```
package com.spentaklabs.view;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;


public class MAView extends View
{
Drawable image;
private String imgName;
private float mPosX;
private float mPosY;

private float mLastTouchX;
private float mLastTouchY;

private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

public MAView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public MAView(Context context,String imgName)
{
    this(context);
    this.imgName = imgName;
    image = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hatshairears0);
    image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
}

public MAView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context,attrs,defStyle);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    image.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

    final int action = ev.getAction();

    switch (action)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        {
            final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
            final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

         // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
            if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                invalidate();
            }

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            break;

        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
        {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: 
        {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        {
            // Extract the index of the pointer that left the touch sensor
            final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);

            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId)
            {
                // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code that would let you drag a View anywhere you want on the screen...

```
package com.matthieu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DragActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener, AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener
{
    private static final String TAG="DragActivity";

    private static final int NOT_DRAGGING = 0;
    private static final int DRAGGING = 1;

    private int state=NOT_DRAGGING;
    private ImageView draggable =null;
    private int dragged_position;

    float current_x, current_y;
    int current_icon = R.drawable.notepad;

    private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Matt", "Xiaohui", "Yong", "Hunt", "Andy", "Ivy", "Guanglong", "Zeyan", "Yanxia",
            "Chris", "Mark", "Matthieu"));
    private ArrayList<Integer> icons = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList( R.drawable.glasses, R.drawable.monkey, R.drawable.normal, R.drawable.smile, R.drawable.wink));
    private ArrayList<Integer> matching;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setupListContent();

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list);
        list.setAdapter(new DragListAdapter());
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

        list.setOnTouchListener(this);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_image);
        image.setImageResource(current_icon);
    }

    private void setupListContent() {
        matching = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<names.size(); i++) {
            matching.add((int) (icons.size() * Math.random()));
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private class DragListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        public DragListAdapter() {
            super(DragActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, names);

        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            }

            row.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);

            name.setText(names.get(position));
            icon.setImageResource(icons.get(matching.get(position)));

            return row;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkOnDropIcon(MotionEvent me) {
        ImageView drop_icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_image);
        Rect icon_rect = new Rect();
        drop_icon.getGlobalVisibleRect(icon_rect);
        Log.d(TAG, "icon at " + icon_rect.left + "<- ->" + icon_rect.right + ", " +
                icon_rect.top + " ^ v" + icon_rect.bottom);
        if ((me.getRawX()<icon_rect.left) || (me.getRawX()>icon_rect.right) ||
                (me.getRawY()<icon_rect.top) || (me.getRawY()>icon_rect.bottom)) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void checkOnDrop(MotionEvent me) {
        boolean onDropIcon = checkOnDropIcon(me);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_image);
        if ((onDropIcon) && (current_icon==R.drawable.notepad)) {
            current_icon = R.drawable.exit;
            image.setImageResource(current_icon);
            image.invalidate();
            return;
        }
        if ((!onDropIcon) && (current_icon==R.drawable.exit)) {
            current_icon = R.drawable.notepad;
            image.setImageResource(current_icon);
            image.invalidate();
            return;
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {
        if (state == NOT_DRAGGING) {
            // get the position of the touch so we know where to place the dragging item if it is a long press
            current_x = me.getRawX();
            current_y = me.getRawY();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.drag_space);

            if (me.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                frame.removeAllViews();
                draggable=null;
                frame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                state=NOT_DRAGGING;

                // check if we dropped a name
                if (checkOnDropIcon(me)) {
                    names.remove(dragged_position);
                    matching.remove(dragged_position);

                    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list);
                    DragListAdapter adapter = (DragListAdapter) list.getAdapter();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                // restore the icon
                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_image);

                current_icon = R.drawable.notepad;
                image.setImageResource(current_icon);
                image.invalidate();
            }
            if (me.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                int frame_position[] = new int[2];
                frame.getLocationOnScreen(frame_position);

                draggable.setPadding(
                        (int) me.getRawX()-frame_position[0]-(draggable.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth()/2),
                        (int) me.getRawY()-frame_position[1]-(draggable.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight()/2),
                        0, 0);
                draggable.invalidate();

                checkOnDrop(me);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        if (state == DRAGGING) {
            Log.d(TAG, "already have an object moving... ?");
            return false;
        }

        FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.drag_space);
        int frame_position[] = new int[2];
        frame.getLocationOnScreen(frame_position);

        // setup everything for dragging
        state = DRAGGING;
        dragged_position = i;

        draggable = new ImageView(this);
        Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
        draggable.setImageBitmap(bm);
        draggable.setAlpha(150);
        draggable.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        draggable.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        draggable.setPadding((int) current_x-frame_position[0]-(bm.getWidth()/2), (int) current_y-frame_position[1]-(bm.getHeight()/2), 0, 0);

        frame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        frame.addView(draggable, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/main_frame"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/main_list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main_image"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="32sp"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/drag_space"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And the list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_icon"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3sp"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm eager to try this out.  In your example here, you use a list simply to hold the items that are being instantiated?

Comment: Correct, and you can drag those items. I just put a picture and some text there to make sure it works correctly...

Comment: I put the apk there: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/44437318/DragActivity-debug.apk so you can try it and see if it does what you expect

Comment: I appreciate the apk.  It looks like this solution will work. Just need to toss the longpress "activate" and also cause it to leave the object when you release your finger (instead of sending it back to its origin)

Comment: Hi would you be kind enough to assist me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493913/why-does-the-value-of-x-does-not-go-all-the-way-to-the-edge-of-the-layout